# Finding character at particular location of String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, charat, binomial-theorem

As a part of a Binomial expansion program, I created a Scanner class (`sc`) on an entered **number + variable**, and another (`scan`)on the first *term* (*a* in **(a+b)<sup>n</sup>**)

Here's my program till now :

```java
import java.util.* ;
public class binomial_expansion
{
    public static long factorial(long x)
    {
        long xf = x ;
        for(long i = 1; i<=x ; i++)
        {
            xf*=i ;
        }
        return xf ;
    }
    
    public static double C(long n, long r)
    {
        double c = factorial(n)/(factorial(n-r)*factorial(r)) ;
        return c ;
    }
    
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        boolean error = false ;
        String a = "" ;
        do {
            if(error)
            {
                System.out.println("Error; Please try again") ;
                error = false ;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter a (separate single variable with space) : ") ;
            a = sc.nextLine() ;
            if(a=="") error = true ;
        } while(error) ;
        
        sc.close() ;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(a) ;
        long x = scan.nextLong() ;
        long x1 = scan.next().charAt(0) ;
    }
}
```

The problem with creating a character variable using `.next().charAt(index)` is that the index number of the character (the single variable) is not known in the string (the length of the integer is not known), and also that the blank space has to be omitted which was entered by the user to separate the integer literal and the character literal. How can the character variable containing the single-digit variable be made ?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your `error` variable which is only ever set to false.

Comment: Save the input to a string, use a regular expression to parse it and capture the individual elements into groups. What exact input do you expect?

Comment: To clarify your question, you're requesting from the user to enter just 1 character and 1 number?

Comment: @khelwood it didn't get copied correctly wait

Comment: First problem, you're using the parameter `x` as a limit in `for(long i = 1; i<=x ; i++)`, but within the loop you're changing `x*=i`. `x` will increase faster than `i`, and the loop won't work. Use another variable (e.g. `var xf = x`) for the return value, and declare your parameter as `final long x` to ensure it's not changed.

Comment: @Reilas for now, only one number, space, and a single digit veriable

Comment: @JohnBayko yup kk

Comment: `error` isn't being used correctly. Get the base case working first, then add error handling.

Comment: @JohnBayko yea done

Comment: You should initialize xf to be $1$ in your factorial program. It looks like this will return $(x!)x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only need one `Scanner` to get the input, which you do with `a = sc.nextLine()`.

From there, find the index of the space, and use the `String.substring` method to derive each value.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
boolean error = false ;
String a = "" ;
do {
    if(error)
    {
        System.out.println("Error; Please try again") ;
        error = false ;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a (separate single variable with space) : ") ;
    a = sc.nextLine() ;
} while(error) ;

sc.close() ;

int indexOf = a.indexOf(' ');
long number = Long.parseLong(a.substring(0, indexOf));
char variable = a.charAt(indexOf + 1);
```

Comment: `a.substring(indexOf + 1).charAt(0)` would be the same as `a.charAt(indexOf + 1)` - just more method call and intermediate `String` created || In *production* code you would also check if `indexOf` is not `-1`...

Comment: @user16320675, you're right, I overlooked that.  I made the change to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a string and then use stringtokenizer to seperate with black spaces. Then use nextToken() to get the integer and variable seperately.

`Long.parseLong()` to convert string to long

```
import java.util.*;
class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str = "12 w";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str," ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        str=st.nextToken();
        System.out.println(str+"-"+x);
    }
}
```

Here I used int, you can use long aswell

Comment: yes StringTokeniser  class can be used here as well as sc.substring

Comment: I would *prefer* a `Scanner` instead of `StringTokenizer` - it separates by whitespaces and also can parse integer (and is a bit newer, or less older)

Comment: @user16320675 Yeah using delimiter would be good for replacing stringtokenizer